# Galaxy Nexus I9250 stuck on x logo after updating yakju to takju

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, boot

My Galaxy Nexus I9250 gets stuck on X logo after I updated yakju to takju (4.2 factory images for takju).

How I can fix this?

Comment: It would help if you have more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can flash back to factory to save your phone.

1. Download latest image of your Galaxy Nexus [Link](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#takju).
2. For example, if you download [android 4.3 takju](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/takju-jwr66y-factory-5104ab1d.tgz), unpack
3. You will see `flash-all.bat` or `flash-all.sh`. If you're using Windows, run `flash-all.bat` with your phone connected the PC and drivers installed. And under Linux , run `flash-all.sh`